# How to bootstrap Windows node using knife EC2 witout internet access

Tags: chef-infra, knife, amazon-ec2

We have strict requirement where "No internet connection is allowed", and one more "Only tested and approved software can be installed". **knife ec2 server create** comand downloads chef-client.msi from opscode web site. I saw that knife **windows** plugin let use custom URL to specify location from where to get msi. AFAIK ec2 plugin has its own bootstrap logic.
How to bootstrap Windows instance using **knife ec2 server create** and specify location of chef-client.msi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `--msi-url` option to control where to download the MSI from. You can also make your own custom bootstrap template if you need even more control. Relevant code https://github.com/chef/knife-ec2/blob/master/lib/chef/knife/ec2_server_create.rb#L747

Comment: Thanks. I tested it by putting msi at local web server.
I do not understand why this is not part of documentation (or I did not look at right place?)
I have found some other options looking into source code but I missed this one :-)
BTW
Any suggested place to start to make bootstrap template?
I found 'knife bootstrap' but I do not know how much is relevant since I am bootstrapping using knife ec2 plugin (or should I ask new question?).